# Can I write bash script to check if certain pattern is matched then the line following next line contains another pattern?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I don't want to build a full sophisticated parser but rather some a simple injection script using bash, sed, awk or grep or any tool that would help to quickly process many files.

Assuming I have a class file stored in `force-app/main/default/classes/Controller.cls` with some contents like following

```
public class Controller {
    public class Model{
        public void init() {
            for ... {
                if ... {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void x() {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();
        try {
            for ... {
                if ... {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //...
        }
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled public String y;
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void z() {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserAdminPermissions();
        try {
            for ... {
                if ... {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //...
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled public String a;

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void b() {
        try {
            for ... {
                if ... {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //...
        }
    }


}
```

and I want to use some bash script to check all methods which are annotated with @AuraEnabled annotation to check if the first line of method body doesn't follow defined pattern like `if ($1 ~ "AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNo") {` then to add a line
`if ($1 ~ "AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNo") {` as the first line of the method body.

Can I achieve that with awk or sed or grep or any other tool without building the full sophisticated parser?

So for the given input file I want the script to skip any methods not annotated with the given annotation and skip any properties and check methods x, y, b. Do nothing for x and y since they already follow the pattern but for method b introduce a new line

```
public class Controller {
    public class Model{
        public void init() {
            for ... {
                if ... {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void x() {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();
        try {
            for ... {
                if ... {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //...
        }
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled public String y;
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void z() {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserAdminPermissions();
        try {
            for ... {
                if ... {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //...
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled public String a;

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void b() {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserAdminPermissions();
        try {
            for ... {
                if ... {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //...
        }
    }


}
```

I have tried to run the following script

```
 class=force-app/main/default/classes/Controller.cls
 
echo $class
awk '\
BEGIN {
    inBrace = 0;
    annotation = 0;
}
{
    if ($0 ~ /@AuraEnabled/) {
        annotation = 1;
    }
    if ($0 ~ /[^;] *{/) {
        inBrace = 1;
        print;
        next;
    }
    if (inBrace == 1 && annotation == 1) {
        if ($1 ~ "AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNo") {
            print
        } else {
            print "        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();";
            print;
        }
        inBrace = 0;
    } else {
        print;
    }
}' $class > $class.copy
mv $class.copy $class
```

but it produces the wrong output, it adds the line to every place where there was opening brace, not only where it was a method declared with desired annotation.

This is the wrong file output I get

```
public class Controller {
    public class Model{
        public void init() {
            for ... {
                if ... {
                }
            }
        }
    }

        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void x() {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();
        try {
            for ... {
                if ... {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();
            //...
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled public String y;

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void z() {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserAdminPermissions();
        try {
            for ... {
                if ... {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();
            //...
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled public String a;

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void b() {
        try {
            for ... {
                if ... {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();
            //...
        }
    }


}
```

Also I don't want the new line to be added in the end of the file.

I tried to use `do {...} } while (getline == 1)` approach but then no lines are printed at all

```
echo $class
awk '\
FNR == 1 {
    inBrace = 0;
    annotation = 0;
    do {
        if ($0 ~ /[^;] @AuraEnabled/) {
            annotation = 1;
            inBrace = 0;
        }
        if ($0 ~ /;/) {
            annotation = 0;
        }
        if ($0 !~ /get/ $0 ~ /{/) {
            inBrace = 1;
            print;
            next;
        }
        if (inBrace == 1 && annotation == 1) {
            if ($1 ~ "AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNo") {
                print
            } else {
                print "        AccessVerificationService.throwExceptionIfNoUserPermissions();";
                print;
            }
            inBrace = 0;
            annotation = 0;
        } else {
            print;
        }
    } while (getline == 1)

    
}' $class > $class.copy
mv $class.copy $class
```

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: *`but only if there was no semicolon before the opening brace.`* ... could you update the sample to include an instance where there *is* a semicolon before the opening brace?

Comment: So your question is "Can I achieve that with awk or sed or grep or any other tool?" and the answer is - not robustly, you need to write a parser for whatever language that code is written in to be able to do what you want robustly. If you just want a best effort solution that'll only work for a specific subset of the language that you provide examples of then - yes and it'd be best done in awk of the tools you mention.

Comment: for the questions about semicolon: I mean that I don't want to change anything for properties which usually end in a semicolon, but only add a line to methods which are annotated with the same annotation.

Comment: I don't want to write a parser (it might be too much level of efforts), I am looking for any elegant and simple solution

Comment: You can have an elegant and simple solution as long as it doesn't need to work robustly for all possible constructs of whatever language that is. By the way, this is the second time I've seen you try to use `getline` in your code - that's usually the wrong approach, see https://web.archive.org/web/20221109201352/http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when/how to use getline.

Comment: A parser is elegant but not simple; a regex is simple but not elegant or often very accurate in the case where you actually need a parser.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand what you meant by `but only if there was no semicolon before the opening brace`, because that could mean `no semi-colon on the preceding line` or `no semi-colon directly before the brace`, but, assuming the latter, the following seems to do what you wanted (tested with your sample input).

```
BEGIN {
    inBrace = 0;
}
{
    if ($0 ~ /[^;] *{/) {
        inBrace = 1;
        print;
        next;
    }
    if (inBrace == 1) {
        if ($1 == "DoSomething();") {
            print
        } else {
            print "    DoSomething();";
            print;
        }
        inBrace = 0;
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```

This also works, and is perhaps clearer to read:

```
BEGIN {
    inBrace = 0;
}
{
    if ($0 ~ /[^;] *{/) {
        inBrace = 1;
        print;
        next;
    }
    if (inBrace == 1) {
        if ($1 == "DoSomething();") {
            print
        } else {
            print "    DoSomething();";
            print;
        }
        inBrace = 0;
        next;
    }
    print;
}
```

If you want to exclude cases where the line before the opening brace ends with a semi-colon, you could add another conditional variable and expand the `if` checks appropriately.

Comment: when I tried to copy your code into parse.sh I tried to execute it like following ./parse.sh       I received the following errors

./parse.sh: line 1: BEGIN: command not found
./parse.sh: line 2: inBrace: command not found
./parse.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./parse.sh: line 3: `}'

Comment: Ah, so I need to prepend `awk '\ ` on the beginning and `' file.cls > output.cls` on the end

Comment: well, still it ignores the @annotation